# Could I use ansible without installing python on managed node?

Tags: python, ansible

I want to use ansible , could I use ansible without installing python on managed node? 
For example, I just want to execute some shell commands on managed nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can, but you have to use the **raw module**:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html